# NumPy ImportError on new conda environment

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, conda

I have just set up a new conda environment from a YAML file. When I try to run the imports below, I receive an import error.

```py
import logging
import yaml
import math
import numpy as np
C:\Users\Jack\anaconda3\envs\rl_floris\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py:139: UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R) MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is not assured. Please install mkl-service package, see http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service
  from . import _distributor_init
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\rl_floris\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py:23
    from . import multiarray

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\rl_floris\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py:10
    from . import overrides

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\rl_floris\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py:6
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found.


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In [1], line 4
    import numpy as np

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\rl_floris\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py:141
    from . import core

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\rl_floris\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py:49
    raise ImportError(msg)

ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.9 from "C:\Users\Jack\anaconda3\envs\rl_floris\python.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.24.3"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found.



The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing NumPy and mkl-service but this doesn't seem to solve the issue. I have also checked both the numpy and python versions in the environment and they match the versions suggested in the error message.